# Qt QML - QModBus read corrupted by QML BusyIndicator/Animation - SingleThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml, modbus

I have a single thread QQuick application with one main window and one class that handles Modbus Write/Read functions. Everything is working fine so far but when I put a BusyIndicator in my qml window to show that the Bus is busy I get CRC mismatches and response timeouts, e.g.:

- "Discarding response with wrong CRC, received: 64580 , calculated CRC: 55067"
- "Read response error: Response timeout. (code: 0x5)" - qt.modbus: (RTU client) Cannot match response with open request, ignoring

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "modbusinterface.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

ModbusInterface modbus;

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                 &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
        QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
engine.load(url);

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("modbus", &modbus);

return app.exec();
}
```

modbusinterface.h

```
#ifndef MODBUSINTERFACE_H
#define MODBUSINTERFACE_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QModbusRtuSerialMaster>
#include <QModbusDevice>
#include <QModbusClient>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

class ModbusInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool busBusy READ busBusy NOTIFY busBusyChanged)

public:
    explicit ModbusInterface(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool busBusy(void) {return m_busBusy;}
    Q_INVOKABLE bool read(int deviceId, int startAddress, quint16 count);

public slots:
    void readReady();

signals:
    void busBusyChanged();

private:
    bool m_busBusy = false;
    QModbusReply *m_lastRequest = nullptr;
    QModbusClient *m_client = nullptr;
};

#endif // MODBUSINTERFACE_H
```

modbusinterface.cpp

```
#include "modbusinterface.h"

ModbusInterface::ModbusInterface(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_client = new QModbusRtuSerialMaster();
    m_client->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialPortNameParameter, "ttyUSB0");
    m_client->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialBaudRateParameter, QSerialPort::Baud19200);
    m_client->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialDataBitsParameter, QSerialPort::Data8);
    m_client->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialParityParameter, QSerialPort::NoParity);
    m_client->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialStopBitsParameter, QSerialPort::OneStop);

    m_client->setTimeout(1000);
    m_client->setNumberOfRetries(1);

    if (!m_client->connectDevice()) {
        qDebug() << "Connect failed: " << m_client->errorString();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Modbus Client is Connected";
    }
}

bool ModbusInterface::read(int deviceId, int startAddress, quint16 count)
{
    QModbusDataUnit RxData;

    if(startAddress>=40000) RxData.setRegisterType(QModbusDataUnit::HoldingRegisters);
    else RxData.setRegisterType(QModbusDataUnit::InputRegisters);

    RxData.setStartAddress(startAddress);
    RxData.setValueCount(count);

    if (!m_client) {
        qDebug() << "!m_client";
        return false;
    }

    if (m_client->state() != QModbusDevice::ConnectedState){
        qDebug() << "Modbus Client is not Connected in read section";
        return false;
    }

    if (auto *reply = m_client->sendReadRequest(RxData, deviceId))
    {
        if (!reply->isFinished()){
            connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, this, &ModbusInterface::readReady);
            m_lastRequest = reply;
            m_busBusy = true;
            emit busBusyChanged();
        } else {
            delete reply;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void ModbusInterface::readReady()
{
    auto reply = qobject_cast<QModbusReply *>(sender());
    if (!reply) return;

    if( reply == m_lastRequest){
        m_busBusy = false;
        emit busBusyChanged();
    }
    reply->deleteLater();

    if (reply->error() == QModbusDevice::NoError)
    {
        qDebug() << reply;
    }
    else if (reply->error() == QModbusDevice::ProtocolError)
    {
        qDebug() << QString("Read response error: %1 (Mobus exception: 0x%2)").
                    arg(reply->errorString()).
                    arg(reply->rawResult().exceptionCode(), -1, 16);
    } else {
        qDebug() << QString("Read response error: %1 (code: 0x%2)").
                    arg(reply->errorString()).
                    arg(reply->error(), -1, 16);
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("ModbusTrial")

    Button{
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "read Modbus"
        onClicked: {
            for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
                modbus.read(i, 30001, 1)
            }
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator{
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: button.bottom
        visible: modbus.busBusy //false
    }
}
```

In this minimal working example I trigger/queue 10 read requests via a qml/c++ interface to my modbusinterface-class. As I acess devices which serveradress is not necessary known I need to scan multiple IDs for valid responses and wanted to display a busyIndicator during that time. That causes the mentioned timeout/CRC errors.
If there's no animation running in my window, the data is received without errors.

- Can this be fixed by using a separate thread to run the modbus read/write methods and how would I implement that? Or would I only increase the misreads by putting the Serial functions in a separate Thread?

As I understand it so far, due to the fact that my application is running in a single thread, the continuous update of the GUI is somehow interfering with the reception of Serial Data.

I used the linux command line tool "stress" to see if I lose data under high cpu load as well but that's not the case.

Interestingly, the first response I get is always valid. So could there be a problem with queuing the requests the way I do? In the doc  it says:

> Note: QModbusClient queues the requests it receives. The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol. For example, the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms issues 6 requests in parallel for one host/port combination.

Kind regards

Comment: Without a [mre], we can't answer your question directly. But I would definitely try a separate thread to see if that solves it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bus is busy"?

Comment: I updated my code samples. By the bus is busy I mean that I sent multiple "readRequests" and during the time it takes to process them - sometimes till the timeout happens - i consider the bus busy

Comment: If you're reading continuous registers, change `count` would be better than read 10 single registers.

Comment: Also `emit busBusyChanged();` should be only done once when `m_busBusy` goes from `false` to `true`.

Comment: @LouisGo yes, if you adress a single device. But I'm reading the 10 registers from different server addresses. Also the busBusy variable doesn't actually impact the receives: If I uncomment everything connected with that variable and just set the BusyIndicator.running to true I still receive only half of the replies correctly

Comment: I also noticed that the response timeout happens way before the timeout value I set...

Comment: And now I solved it for me I guess:
If I put Qthread::msleep(msec) in the reply::finished interrupt handler readReady() with msec being >40 ( which is roughly the response time of the modbus servers), it works. I thought that the asynchronuous API of QModbusReply is foolproof but not for me maybe :P

If someone could tell me why that fixes it though, it'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: On the other hand that really adds up on the time it takes to scan all the devices... puh.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue:

As I thought the qml rendering engine, scene graph or whatever you call it, caused missed frames of the modbus reception. I guess somehow threading might have helped with that, but I was not able to fix it by having the modbusInterface run in a separate thread.

In the end the solution was to enable the threaded render loop of the scene graph as stated here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#threaded-render-loop-threaded

I.e. by putting

```
qputenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP","threaded");
```

in my main().